# Awk or Sed: grep data between XML multilines

Tags: regex, xml, awk, sed

I'm trying to grep and show data from XML file through Awk or Sed, but reached an impasse...

In details I'm looking how to do the following: (1) get value from 'mt' tag, (2) analyze all 'moid' tags which contain 'Source = _SYSTEM' only, (3) get value of 'Host=' and in next line get value of 'r' tag, (4) then print value from 'mt' tag, (5) then print value of 'Host=' and print value of 'r' tag, (6) sum values from all 'Host=' and print it;

The problem here is that I have many tags and many lines in the XML.

Here is my XML to parse,

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<neid>
<neun></neun>
<nedn>element=home</nedn>
</neid>
<mi>
    <mts>20150517032500.0+0200</mts>
    <gp>300</gp>
    <mt>Name1</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super1.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source1</moid>
        <r>1</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super2.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source2</moid>
        <r>1</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super2.stackoverflow.com, Source = _SYSTEM</moid>
        <r>2</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super2.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source3</moid>
        <r>1</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super1.stackoverflow.com, Source = _SYSTEM</moid>
        <r>2</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super1.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source4</moid>
        <r>1</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
<mi>
    <mts>20150517032500.0+0200</mts>
    <gp>300</gp>
    <mt>Name2</mt>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super1.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source1</moid>
        <r>11</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super2.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source2</moid>
        <r>11</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super2.stackoverflow.com, Source = _SYSTEM</moid>
        <r>22</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super2.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source3</moid>
        <r>11</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super1.stackoverflow.com, Source = _SYSTEM</moid>
        <r>22</r>
    </mv>
    <mv>
        <moid>Host=super1.stackoverflow.com, Source = Source4</moid>
        <r>11</r>
    </mv>
</mi>
```

Expected result,

```
Name1:
   super1.stackoverflow.com: 2
   super2.stackoverflow.com: 2
   TOTAL: 4

Name2:
   super1.stackoverflow.com: 22
   super2.stackoverflow.com: 22
   TOTAL: 44
```

UPD: My requirement is to use Awk or Sed because unfortunately it's impossible (forbidden to install it on the host) to use xmllint or xmlstarlet or something similar.

Thank you a lot in advance!

Comment: consider using a standard xml processing technology ( xslt, expat library, etc. )

Comment: It's a job for [xmllint](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmllint/info) or [xmlstarlet](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/xmlstarlet/info) or something similar.

Comment: That does not look like valid XML, having two root nodes.

Comment: @Wintermute Yes, it's true that host can have the same path in XML...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file structure is exactly same as mentioned and will not change the below should do the trick

> `sed -n -e 's/ *<mt>\(.*\)<\/mt>/\1:/p;/<moid>..*Source = _SYSTEM/{N;s/\n//g;s/.*Host=\(.*\), Source = _SYSTEM.*<r>\(.*\)<\/r>/\1:\2/p}' file.txt|awk -F":" -v x=0 '{if(NR==1){print $0;next};if($2==""){print "TOTAL:" x "\n" $0;x=0;} else {x=x+$2;print $0;}}END{print "TOTAL:" x}'`
>
> Sed is stripping off everything other than what exists in `<mt <moid> or <r>` tags. Awk then works on the generated file and provides the sum and the TOTAL value